# How really 'import' works in Python?

Tags: python

I can't wrap my head around how 'import' statement works in Python.

It is said to search for the packages in directories returned by `sys.path()`. However, even if `sys` module is *available* automatically in every Python program it's not *imported* automatically. So does `import` statement import `sys` module under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two phases which you are getting a little confused.

1. Python has to find the actual file (containing code) that you want to import, parse it, execute it, and store it somewhere.
2. It then has to bind the name of the imported module locally to the module object.

That is, the process "find the module `sys` and turn it into a module object" is not the same as "define the variable `sys` to mean the module".

You can check which modules have been loaded by looking in `sys.modules`.

---

As a separate issue, there are a few basics of Python that are actually hardcoded into the interpreter, not represented as separate files on disk. `sys` is one of these modules: there is no `sys.py` file; instead, it's compiled C code that's included in the `python.exe` binary.

Answer (score 3):

### `sys` module vs `import` statement - aka. "chicken or the egg?"

I believe [`sys` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) says it all:

> This module provides access to some variables used or maintained by the interpreter and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter. It is always available.

So, to put it shortly and in different words: **interpreter has some variables that you can access by using `sys` module** - `sys.path` is one of such variables.

### Question no. 2. - How `import` works

When it comes to "how `import` statement works", you can read about it here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import. However, it is not really related to the main part of your question: the relation of `import` statement and importing `sys` module.